# Autofocus in Samsung S8+

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, autofocus

A wrote an application using a camera ([Camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary)) some time ago. And it worked with Samsung S5 (Android 6). But with S8+ (Android 8) camera doesn't focus anymore. It's going from `CONTROL_AF_STATE_INACTIVE` to `CONTROL_AF_STATE_ACTIVE_SCAN` to `CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED` (and then cycles through last two states) but the camera doesn't focus.

But when for the first time I postpone autofocus start (for example for 1 - 2 seconds after opening camera device) camera focuses - but only this time. And then it backs to cycling through these states without focusing.

The only thing that helps is reopening camera device but it's unacceptable because of delay.

I was trying to use `CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` instead of `CONTROL_AF_MODE_MACRO` and this works for S8 but doesn't work for S5 :/

Does anybody have an issue like this? I'll try to prepare SSCE but maybe somebody knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

this is a know glitch ...the Samsung forums have a possible solution:
https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S8-Questions-and-Answers/Camera-Not-Focusing-and-Blurry-Photos/td-p/103058 - which appears to be a manufacturing / mechanical issue.

**tapping the back might loosen the stuck lens** (eg. while it switches the modes back and forth). I'd still check for the occasion, that it may still behave alike that when running on some other S8+ device. it's not exactly what one would expect from a brand-new smartphone, but there seems to be too little precision at the lens clearance. maybe try to RMA that device?

Comment: But builtin camera app works OK. A also have QR codes scanner app which also works (i suspect it uses old Camera library). I'm afraid it's something in my code. I'll try to post some of it here.

Comment: @MoonWolf it might not supply enough power to the AF servo or send the wrong op codes, when being accessed through camera2 API... think the Samsung HW test code for this is `*#0*#`. I don't have an S8+, but they all write that tapping beside the lens helps. in case the camera2 API is at fault, you should file a bug against it.

Comment: someone after RMA also wrote "faulty electrical component", which somehow confirms my suspicion ...the hardware issue might only surface when camera2 is being used to access it - while it should work in 100% of the cases, no matter which API. you could test your code on an emulator, with a web-cam attached... in order to rule that out.